# How do I center bottom navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I need to center the bottom navigation menu in mobile. I've provided an image of what it currently looks like. Can someone help me in getting my code to where it needs to be?

[image]

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Call</a></li>
</ul>

@media (max-width: 767px){
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #219ae2;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-size: 10px !important;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily replace `li {float: left;}` with `li {display: inline-block}` then center the `li`'s by adding `text-align: center` to `ul`, check the below snippet:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #219ae2;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     text-size: 10px !important;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 8px 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #111;
}

.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
}
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Call</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That did the trick, plus I also modified this line:


    li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    {

Comment: glad to hear that :) you could accept my answer if this solved your issue.